# Length of the arc drawn by a particle moving on a circle is differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, euclidean-geometry, physics, circles

Let the endpoint of a differentiable, vector-valued function **a**$(t):(t_a\,..t_b)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ move on a circle in an Euclidean plane. Let $t_0\in(t_a\,..t_b)$. Let $s(t)$ be the length of the arc between $t_0$ and point **a**$(t)$. Let there be a positive real number $\delta$ such that $\forall t:0<|t-t_0|<\delta:s(t)-s(t_0)\neq0$.

My (physics) book uses a proof which seems to imply that $s(t)$, where $t$ is time, is differentiable in respect to $t$. How to prove its differentiability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arclength is $s(t)=\int_{t_0}^t\vert\mathbf a'(\tau)\vert \mathrm d\tau$

So, $s(t)$ is differentiable because $s'(t)=\vert\mathbf a'(t)\vert$ exists: composition of continuous functions and the derivative of $\mathbf a(t)$,  that exists.